# Map method with specific attributes only

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Book model and an User model. User has many books.

From my schema:

```
create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "email",                  default: "",    null: false
  t.string   "full_name"
  t.string   "gender"
  t.integer  "age"
  t.string   "country"
  t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true, using: :btree
  t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true, using: :btree
end
```

My goal is to map the User model into an array of user objects:

[{...}, {...}, {...}]

with objects only with attributes:

```
{id: 15, full_name: "Tim Test"}
```

I can map the users from the books with

```
@user = @books.map { |u| u.user }.uniq
```

But how can I only map with the attributes id and full_name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `pluck`, it is the cheapest way to do what you want:

```
User.pluck(:id, :fullname)
#=>[[1, "Tim Test1"]
#   [2, "Tim Test2"]]
```

Then you can simply iterate it. 
In this case, you don't create a heavy ActiveRecord object, so it's faster and consumes less memory than `select`.

If you want result exactly like in your question, you can simply build it:

```
User.pluck(:id, :fullname)
    .map { |e| [:id, :fullname].zip(e).to_h }
```